# Get users for multiple groups

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I have about 22 groups in my application, all starting with **idm2cbd_app_**.
I would like to fetch all the users assigned to these groups. Of course there is an option to iterate and query Graphh 22 times, but I am looking for any better way when it comes to performance.

Do you have any ideas how to achieve that? For now I can only fetch the groups using

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$filter=startswith(displayName, 'idm2bcd_app_')

but I am not able to join the users here. From the users API I also couldn't find any filter that would allow me to filter the assigned groups :(

I would appreciate your help thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to expand members?

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$filter=startswith(displayName, 'e')&$expand=members
```

When using `$select`, you can specify which properties will be returned

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$filter=startswith(displayName, 'idm2bcd_app_')&$Select=id,displayName&$expand=members($select=id,userPrincipalName)
```

Comment: Oh thanks, that might work, but I have insufficient privileges for now. I will test that. Thanks!!!